# Scope problem nesting Javascript Objects

Tags: javascript, scope

I am writing some Javascript code using jQuery to display specially formatted widgets in a browser.  I've had success, but now I'm working on refactoring my code for two reasons.

(1) I wish to be able to easily use the widget more than once and have a Javascript object referring to each one.
(2) I wish to do it the right way so that my code is totally reusable and doesn't little the global namespace with all sorts of objects and functions.

I'm having a scoping problem and I wish to fix the problem and improve my understanding of Javascript scope.  I've condensed this problem down to a tiny code snippet that illustrates what I'm doing:

```
  function getMyObject() {
      var theObject = {
          doThis: function () { },
          doThat: function () { },
          combinations: {
              doThisTwice: function () { doThis(); doThis(); },
              doThatTwice: function () { doThat(); doThat(); }
          }
      };
      return theObject;
  }

  var myObject = getMyObject();
  myObject.combinations.doThisTwice();
```

I've declared a function that returns an object.

However, when I try to execute the function `combinations.doThisTwice()`, the program throws an error saying that `doThis()` is out of scope.  How do I refer to the function `doThis` in the scope of `combinations.doThisTwice`?

**Update:**  Thank you kindly for the answer to my question:  Replace `doThis()` with `theObject.doThis()` inside the function `doThisTwice()`.  This works, but I don't understand why.

I would have thought that the name `theObject` would not be valid until the end of the object declaration.  I think I must misunderstand some fundamental aspect of Javascript... probably because of the C-like syntax.

Comment: Yeah, JS is weird like that. Google for Javscript scope and closures. You'll have a better understanding of how scoping works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
function getMyObject() {
    var theObject = {
        doThis: function () { },
        doThat: function () { },
        combinations: {
            doThisTwice: function () { theObject.doThis(); theObject.doThis(); },
            doThatTwice: function () { theObject.doThat(); theObject.doThat(); }
        }
    };
    return theObject;
}
```

var myObject = getMyObject();
  myObject.combinations.doThisTwice();

You reference 'theObject' from an outer scope to call the functions in an inner object.

Comment: Try inheriting from `theObject` with prototypes or copying `theObject` to another variable and it won't work anymore. Why do you need `this` in the first place if you just refer the object by its variable?

Answer (score 2):

`doThis` is not defined in the functions scope, so it will traverse up the scope chain, but not find it.

You can reference it by

```
theObject.doThis();
```

However, more readable might be if you define your function like this:

```
  function getMyObject() {
      function doThis() {};
      function doThat() {};

      var theObject = {
          doThis: doThis,
          doThat: doThat,
          combinations: {
              doThisTwice: function () { doThis(); doThis(); },
              doThatTwice: function () { doThat(); doThat(); }
          }
      };
      return theObject;
  }
```

But in this case, whenever you change `doThis` from the outside, `doThisTwice` will still reference the original function.

Answer (score 0):

In `doThisTwice`, use `theObject.doThis();` instead of `doThis();`